# Use scrapy in simple pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping a page that have a simple structure, I use chrome to get an idea of the xpaths I need to use, but in this case isn't working.

I got this kind of xpaths:

```
/html/body/text()[1]

/html/body/div[9]/p/span[2]/text()
```

But when I try:

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div[9]/p/span[2]/text()')
```

or

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div[9]/p/span[2]/text()').extract()
```

I don't get any response, just an empty list

Comment: Please share the URL of the page you are working with.

Comment: http://www.bbb.org/boston/business-reviews/appliances-major-dealers/dracut-appliance-center-inc-in-dracut-ma-76793/ReadReviews?page=1&exp=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your XPath expression. Demo from the Shell:

```
$ scrapy shell "http://www.bbb.org/boston/business-reviews/appliances-major-dealers/dracut-appliance-center-inc-in-dracut-ma-76793/ReadReviews?page=1&exp=1" -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36"
>>> print(response.xpath("//span[. = 'Comment from the Business']/following-sibling::span/text()").extract_first())
Mr, ********,
Thank you very much for your positive review.  It's great to hear your install went smoothly. *** (our sales manager of over 45 years) and *** (Sales for over 10 years) have been notified of this positive response and truly appreciated it.  We look forward to service you again in the future!!
```

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez sure, in this case the `.` refers to the text of the current node. Basically, we are locating element by text and then get the very next element after it.